# Calling a derived-class implementation of a pure virtual function statically using a function in the base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, pure-virtual

There's some discussion of this topic elsewhere in stackoverflow, but I haven't really found a clear answer to my question.

My setup is like this:

```
class BaseClass
{
    virtual short return_number_for_thing1(std::string thing1)=0; //note the pure virtual
    virtual short return_number_for_thing2(std::string thing2)=0;
    virtual short return_number_for_thing(std::string thing); //virtual is probably not necessary here, I can get rid of it if need be
}

short BaseClass::return_number_for_thing(std::string thing)
{ //pretend thing1 and thing2 are enum'ed somewhere
    if      (thing == thing1) return return_number_for_thing1(thing);
    else if (thing == thing2) return return_number_for_thing2(thing);
}

class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
    short return_number_for_thing1(std::string thing1);
    short return_number_for_thing2(std::string thing2);
}

class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{
    short return_number_for_thing1(std::string thing1);
    short return_number_for_thing2(std::string thing2);
}
```

My question is, why can't I write code like this:

```
short number_i_want = DerivedClass2::return_number_for_thing(thing);
```

I sort of understand that trying to call return_number_for_thing from a BaseClass pointer doesn't make sense, since it doesn't know whether to call the routines for DerivedClass1 or DerivedClass2, but if I give it the scope of DerivedClass2, shouldn't it be able to figure out what I want? For now, I create a blank instance of DerivedClass2 or DerivedClass1 when I need to, but it seems to me that I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: None of your methods are declared `static`, so they need an instance of the class to be called on.

Comment: There's no such thing like _Static virtual functions_, period.

Comment: Well, that's part of the trouble. I can declare return_number_for_thing to be static, but I can't declare return_number_for_thing1 or return_number_for_thing2 static, even in the derivedclasses because the compiler tells me that it can't be both virtual and static. Declaring return_number_for_thing static isn't enough.

Comment: Its simply a paradox to have a polymorphic static method, if you already know the type there is no need for polymorphism is there?

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, suggest a different title if you like

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to explicitly call a virtual function belonging to a specific class in the hierarchy. If so try `DerivedClass2 *ptrVar = new DerivedClass2(); ptrVar->DerivedClass2::return_number_for_thing(thing);`

Comment: @Nickolai You might be interested in [static polymorphism patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: @Captain Oblivious: So, I still have to create an instance of DerivedClass2, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, virtual and static don't mix.

- `virtual` = concrete operation depends on the type of an object.
- `static` = you don't need an object.

It is certainly possible to imagine such a thing, however. If C++ had something like meta types, allowing you to treat regular **types as objects**, then it would not be such a strange idea anymore.

Pseudo-code (using an **imaginary** syntax):

```
void f(Class base_class)
{
   base_class.StaticMethod();
}

struct Base
{
  virtual static StaticMethod(); // impossible in C++
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  virtual static StaticMethod(); // impossible in C++
};

f(Base); // impossible in C++
f(Derived); // impossible in C++
```

The desire to create something like static virtual functions is sometimes a symptom for the real need (which C++ cannot fulfill out of the box): treating types as objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function virtual or static , not both.

A virtual function must have a vtable pointer which requires an instance of an object, a static function cannot (by definition) have an instance to which it relates.

If you declare the functions as e.g:

```
virtual short return_number_for_thing1(std::string thing1)=0;
```

then you must create an instance and use it e.g. `m_Instance->return_number_for_thing1(...)` (but since you are not using any member variables it would seem this doesnt really make sense).

If you declare the functions as static:

```
static short return_number_for_thing1(std::string thing1)
```

Then you must invoke the function statically `BaseClass::return_number_for_thing1()`, if you provide a static version of the same function in the derived class it now becomes an override and you choose which one you call at compile time with either `BaseClass::return_number_for_thing1` or `DerivedClass::return_number_for_thing1`..

Your question still doesnt really make sense as stated since you cannot use a virtual function statically.  Statically implies that you want to use it without any instance , its simply like a c function but hidden in the namespace of the class (and obeys privacy).   Virtual functions require an instance on which to operate.

Answer (score 0):

Making `static virtual` methods isn't possible, quoting [C++11 standard N3337 - 10.3.10](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf):

> [ Note: The virtual specifier implies membership, so a virtual
>   function cannot be a nonmember (7.1.2) function. **Nor can a virtual
>   function be a static member**, since a virtual function call **relies on a
>   specific object for determining which function to invoke**. A virtual
>   function declared in one class can be declared a friend in another
>   class. —end note ]

Comment: Clearly my title has taken focus away from the actual question... I've changed the title to be more reflective of what I'm actually trying to do

Comment: Virtual functions are bounded with instances. You may create static instance (singleton) and use it like: `DerivedClass2::Instance().return_number_for_thing(thing);`